# AngularJs's templateUrl : Url or ID?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS docs provide a `templateUrl` example :

using :

```
  //ngApp...
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div my-customer></div>
    </div>
```

And in the controller :

```
....directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
  })
```

Where my-customer.html is an **external** file   :

[image]

All ok. but they provide the option to edit it (via [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FjXQb/)) :

But there- it is as a **template** tag ! :

```
<div ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div my-customer></div>
  </div>



      <!-- my-customer.html -->
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-customer.html">
        Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
      </script>
    </div>
```

**Question :**

How does NG knows if it's an external file or is it an Tag element ID ? and how can I force it to a certain type ?

(p.s. - didn't find it in the [**docs**](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_source)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will add to what @QuarK started with, perhaps filling in a bit more detail.

The `$templateCache` is used as a repository for templates once they have been resolved (inline or from a file).

The [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7aef2d54e0a48fae18a289813f699962d8310565/src/ng/directive/script.js) of the `script` tag with `text/ng-templates` looks like this:

```
var scriptDirective = ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      if (attr.type == 'text/ng-template') {
        var templateUrl = attr.id,
            // IE is not consistent, in scripts we have to read .text but in other nodes we have to read .textContent
            text = element[0].text;

        $templateCache.put(templateUrl, text);
      }
    }
  };
}];
```

You can see that if a `script` tag is found, and the `attr.type` is `text/ng-template`, then angular puts the content into the `$templateCache` indexed by the `templateUrl`.

Using `script` tags like this has only been introduced recently to Angular.  So, this is an option that allows an inline definition without requiring an external file.  However, underneath, once resolved, both use the same mechanism to be read and compiled (`$templateCache`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I force it to : "go to the server and don't look at tags? "

Comment: you can simply do not call two templates with the same name :)

Comment: Not exactly sure.  You can reference `$templateCache` directly and make remove caching.  I'm not sure of the granularity on offer here though.  Here is a link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/bxrpsImO0rY

Comment: If script found then it uses it . What if not found ? The code does use that situation ???

Comment: I'm assuming if it is not found in the cache, then the template will attempt to be fetched from the server.  And if it is not found there then error (with 404).

Answer (score 0):

This is through $templateCache, you can find the documentation in it's API:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache)

Comment: Well, templates are loaded when are going to be used, I can imagine if angular finds a template you are calling in a script tag, will load this before asking the server if a partial with the given file name exists..